hyperref - \hypertarget/\hyperlink - What is the best way to ensure that both ascenders and descenders of the phrase to be scrolled to can be seen?
With the example
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{DestinationA}{Text of link to DestinationA}

\hyperlink{DestinationB}{Text of link to DestinationB}

\newpage

\hypertarget{DestinationA}{Text belonging to DestinationA}\\
\hypertarget{DestinationB}{Text belonging to DestinationB}

\end{document}


the \hypertarget with the destination-name DestinationA is created while TeX is in vertical mode.
When viewing the resulting .pdf-file, clicking on "Text of link to DestinationA" leads to vertical scrolling so that both the ascenders and the descenders of the glyphs of the phrase "Text belonging to DestinationA" can be seen.

the \hypertarget with the destination-name DestinationB is created while TeX is in horizontal mode.
When viewing the resulting .pdf-file, clicking on "Text of link to DestinationB" leads to vertical scrolling so that only the descenders of the glyphs of the phrase "Text belonging to DestinationB" can be seen.


(The author of this question tested this with TeX Live 2020, hyperref 2021-02-10 v7.00j, using pdf-viewers Okular 1.3.2, xpdf 3.04 and AdobeReader 9 at a (not too) large zoom factor.)
TeX novices probably do not expect this kind of vertical scrolling behavior.
What is the best way to ensure that in any case vertical scrolling is so that both ascenders and descenders of the glyphs of the phrase that shall be scrolled to can be seen?

(Currently the author of this question tends to suggest using \Hy@raisedlink as in
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{DestinationA}{Text of link to DestinationA}

\hyperlink{DestinationB}{Text of link to DestinationB}

\makeatletter\newpage

\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{DestinationA}{}}Text belonging to DestinationA\\
\Hy@raisedlink{\hypertarget{DestinationB}{}}Text belonging to DestinationB

\end{document}

. But he does so while thinking that it is not ensured that this is the best way of coping with the issue.)

In texlive 2024 I would suggest to use \MakeLinkTarget. It raises a target by \normalbaselineskip:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{DestinationA}{Text of link to DestinationA}

\hyperlink{DestinationB}{Text of link to DestinationB}

\newpage

\MakeLinkTarget*{DestinationA}Text belonging to DestinationA\\
\MakeLinkTarget*{DestinationB}Text belonging to DestinationB

\end{document}

In older texlive raise the box e.g. with a \raisebox. There is no need to use internal hyperref commands for this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\hyperlink{DestinationA}{Text of link to DestinationA}

\hyperlink{DestinationB}{Text of link to DestinationB}

\newpage

\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{DestinationA}{}}Text belonging to DestinationA\\
\raisebox{\normalbaselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\hypertarget{DestinationB}{}}Text belonging to DestinationB

\end{document}

Generally I would recommend to add a target in hmode (and so to add \leavevmode before it). For tagging this is better as the target then gets the correct structure number.
